# Django ForeignKey filtering whole object or object_id

Tags: django, django-models

I know that `object_id` is more efficient than `object.id`
but is this rule working for ForeignKey filtering ?

Is

```
Model.objects.filter(author_id=author_obj.id)
```

or

```
Model.objects.filter(author_id=author_id)
```

more efficient than

```
Model.objects.filter(author=author_obj)
```

Comment: You can use just: `Model.objects.filter(author=author_id)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in [Queries over related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#queries-over-related-objects) section of documentation there's no difference between `author_obj.id` and `author_obj`:

> For example, if you have a Blog object b with id=5, the following
>   three queries would be identical:

```
Entry.objects.filter(blog=b) # Query using object instance
Entry.objects.filter(blog=b.id) # Query using id from instance
Entry.objects.filter(blog=5) # Query using id directly
```

Personally I use `entry.blog_id` as a rule in my projects as it does not generate extra query.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, best is:

```
Model.objects.filter(author_id=author_id)
```

Because field author_id exists in `Model`

With
`Model.objects.filter(author_id=author_obj.id)`. This will execute one query for find author_obj, and get field `id` in this.